# How to match optional group, if it is already matched by main group?

Tags: regex

I have input strings like:

```
any[sym)bol_text
any[sym)bol_text (any[sym)bol_text) any[sym)bol_text
any[sym)bol_text (this_text)
any[sym)bol_text2 (this_text)Fzcj
```

And I have regexp:

```
(?<text>[^\r\n]+)(?:\(this_text\))?
```

But I can't handle strings with `(this_text)` optional group. It matches by first one, but I don't need this exact text in output

Comment: Like this: `^(?<text>.*?)(?:\(this_text\))?$`

Comment: I simplified example, in real situation string can have some specific symbols at the end

Comment: Please provide the exact, real-life test case.

Comment: Thanks for advice, don't know what happened with me, it's obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?<text>.+?)(?:\(this_text\).*)?$
```

So yes, last group should contains handling any text and ends with `$`